# Saving m2m field in Django Admin fails with "ValueError: needs to have a value before this many-to-many relationship can be used"

Tags: django, orm, django-admin, many-to-many, m2m

I got the following (relevant) models. supplies is a many-to-many field.

```
class Supplies(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    name_html = models.CharField(max_length=100L)
    name_verbose = models.CharField(max_length=150L)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'supplies'
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name_html

class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=135)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    supplies = models.ManyToManyField(Supplies, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'manufacturer'
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
        return self.country
```

Intermediary table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `manufacturer_supplies` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `manufacturer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `supplies_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `manufacturer_id` (`manufacturer_id`),
  KEY `supplies_id` (`supplies_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=174 ;
ALTER TABLE `manufacturer_supplies`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `manufacturer_supplies_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`supplies_id`) REFERENCES `supplies` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `manufacturer_supplies_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`manufacturer_id`) REFERENCES `manufacturer` (`id`);
```

The whole things shows up perfectly in the Django Admin with `filter_horizontal`. But when I'm trying to save a new "Manufacturer", I get: `ValueError: "<Manufacturer: thisIsTheManufacturerName>" needs to have a value for field "manufacturer" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.`

I suppose by "manufacturer" the field `manufacturer_id` from the intermediary table is the cause of error. I'm pretty lost...

**History**
When I designed my database layout, I didn't know that Django could handle m2m relationships itself. So i startet with a m2m Model defined with `through`. I got the same error. So i deleted my model, DB table and ran `manage.py syncdb`. Then Django created the intermediary table itself. Because I switched again, I posted the intermediary table layout, just to rule out errors.

Comment: What is that custom sql? Is it yours? If yes, where did you see that something like that is necessary? Have you read even the tiniest bit of django's documentation?

Comment: I added a note why I added the DB layout. I have read the 1.5 documentation about m2m, amongst many other forum posts, blogs and Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: Try dropping the entire database, `syncdb` and try again.

Comment: The exact same behaviour, unfortunately.

Comment: I assume that you removed all your custom sql prior to dropdb/syncdb. Right? Also, I noticed that you have `blank=True` but not `null=True`. You do understand that this means, that your form won't require `supplies` but your database will. So this assumes that you're doing something custom on Manufacturer's `save()` method. Also your Manufacturer's `__unicode__` method has 2 return statements. Other than that, I'm stumped, I can't think of anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem itself isn't solved, but the reason why it fails is now clear to me:

In admin.py, I show the field with a `list_display` (which I unfortunately didn't mention here because I thought it was unrelated) - but the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) say
:

> ManyToManyField fields aren’t supported, because that would entail
>   executing a separate SQL statement for each row in the table. If you
>   want to do this nonetheless, give your model a custom method, and add
>   that method’s name to list_display. (See below for more on custom
>   methods in list_display.)